# Parallelogram law in Normed vector space without an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $V$ be any $\mathbb{K}$-vector space with norm $\|\cdot\|\,.$

I know that the *Parallelogram law* holds if the norm is induced by some inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, i.e.

$$
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}
\newcommand{\skp}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}\begin{array}{rcl}
\norm{a+b}^2+\norm{a-b}^2 &=& \skp{a+b}{a+b} + \skp{a-b}{a-b} \\
 &=& \skp{a}{a+b}+\skp{b}{a+b} + \skp{a}{a-b}-\skp{b}{a-b} \\
&=& \skp{a}{a}+\skp{a}{b}+\skp{b}{a}+\skp{b}{b}+\skp{a}{a}-\skp{a}{b}-\skp{b}{a}+\skp{b}{b}\\
&=& 2\left(\skp{a}{a}+\skp{b}{b}\right) \\
&=& 2\left(\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2\right)
\end{array}$$

**However**, does the Parallelogram law hold if the norm is **not** induced by some inner product? Do you have a proof or a counter example for this case?

Comment: It's a common exercise that if the parallelogram law holds, the norm is induced by an inner product. Known as the polarization identity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paralelogram law holds if and only if the norm is induced by an inner product (over characteristic $\ne 2$):

Supposing the paralelogramma law, 
Let $\langle a,b\rangle:=\displaystyle\frac12\left(\|a+b\|^2 - \|a\|^2-\|b\|^2\right)$.

---

For $\Bbb K=\Bbb C$, we can define a hermitian inner product: 
Let $\langle a,b\rangle:=\displaystyle\frac14\left(\|a+b\|^2+i\|a+ib\|^2-\|a-b\|^2-i\|a-ib\|^2\right)$.

Comment: Precisely that "The paralelogram law holds if and only if the norm is induced by an inner product." @user127001

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check that the given definitions are indeed inner products and that $\langle a,a\rangle=\|a\|^2$ in both cases.

Comment: I'm not aware of norm making sense for a general field because norm requires absolute value. For real numbers, it is not obvious that a norm which satisfies the parallelogram law must be generated by an inner-product. It is not easy to show that the expression for the inner-product that you have given is bilinear over the reals, for example. A continuity argument is required to prove such a thing. The same thing is true for the case of complex scalars, too.

Answer (score 3):

It's a non-trivial exercise to show that
$$
    (a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(\|a+b\|^{2}-\|a\|^{2}-\|b\|^{2})
$$
actually defines an inner-product when the parallelogram law holds for a norm $\|\cdot\|$ over the field of real numbers. The scalar linearity can only be shown for rational numbers directly, and then a continuity argument is required to extend to all real scalars. The full proof is not simple, only assuming that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm.

Comment: Do you know where I can find this kind of proof (full one)? I've been trying to show that every norm in $\mathbb{R}$ comes from an inner product.

Comment: @DrHAL Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, 3rd edition, Question 21.

Comment: Full proof can be found in Kubrusly's *The Elements of Operator Theory*, under Theorem 5.5 (von Neumann).