# Is every Banach space embedded in a reflexive space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Can every Banach space be continuously embedded in a reflexive Banach space? As for example for $ L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)$, where $ \Omega\subset R^n$ is a bounded open set.

Comment: The second example you ask about is a Hilbert space, and is therefore a reflexive Banach space.

Comment: I think you can modify Tomek's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532856/is-every-banach-space-densely-embedded-in-a-hilbert-space) to show that the answer is "no" (reflexive spaces have equivalent strictly convex renormings).

Comment: What is "embedding"?  So, for example, is the set-theoretic inclusion $L^\infty[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ a "continuous embedding"?  You do not require the image to be closed?

Comment: By the continuous embedding, I mean that : $\|y\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C \|y\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}, \forall y\in L^\infty(\Omega) $ for some constant $C>0,$ without any constraint on the image.

Comment: I have seen the Tomek's answer. But the strict convexity property is not preserved by equivalence of norm.

Comment: Sorry for Keen, here I gave an example of such an Embedding ($L^\infty $ in the Hilbert $L^2$) : it is not a part of the question