# Extending a non-compact operator to a non-compact operator between Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be separable Banach spaces, and $S: X \rightarrow Y$ be a non-compact (continuous) operator. Can I always find two separable Hilbert spaces $H_1, H_2$ and continuous operators $T: H_1 \rightarrow X, T_2: Y \rightarrow H_2$ such that
$$T_2 S T_1: H_1 \rightarrow H_2 $$
is non-compact?

I believe the answer is positive, but I cannot come up with a proof.

The most promising attempt relied on the fact that for each separable Banach space $B$ we can find Hilbert spaces $H$ and $G$ s.t. $H$ is densely embedded in $B$ and $B$ is densely embedded in $G$, see Lemma 4.48 in
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.03591.pdf and the answer of shalop in the following post [Is every Banach space densely embedded in a Hilbert space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532856/is-every-banach-space-densely-embedded-in-a-hilbert-space)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since separable Hilbert spaces are isomorph to $l^2$, we can reduce the question to $H_1=H_2=l^2$.
According to [Pitt's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218284/proof-of-pitts-theorem), every linear and continuous operator from $l^p$ to $l^q$ with $1\le q<p<\infty$ is compact. Hence the answer to the question is NO for $X=l^p$ ($p<2$) or $Y=l^q$ ($2<q<\infty$).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know Pitt's theorem and was all the time on the wrong track. I was also wondering - rather out of sheer curiosity - is there some nice characterization of Banach spaces for which such "double sided extension" is actually always possible?